In general, does $P(R|N)>P(R)$ implies $P(N|R)>P(N)$ ? Seems to be confirmed by Venn diagrams example but contradiction with Bayes' theorem
Let $R$ and $N$ be two dependent events, such that $P(R|N)>P(R)$. Does this implies that $P(N|R)>P(N)$? The odds are this is true (and equivalently $P(R|N)<P(R)$ implies $P(N|R)<P(N)$). I have drawn a few Venn diagrams and it turns out to be verified, "graphically".
On the other hand, the Bayes' theorem seems to imply that $P(N|R)<P(N)$ always, independently of whether $P(R|N)/P(R)$ is greater or less than $1$.
In fact, Bayes' theorem writes as (after dividing numerator and denominator by $P(R|N)$):
$$P(N |R) =  \frac{P(N)}{P(N) + \frac{P(R|\overline{N} )}{P(R|N)}(1-P(N))} $$

Here are some Venn diagrams area values I have roughly estimated:
Case $1$:

$P(R) \approx 1/20$
$P(N) \approx 1/15$
$P(R|N) \approx 1/2$
$P(N|R) \approx 1/2$

Case $2$:

$P(R) \approx 1/4$
$P(N) \approx 1/10$
$P(R|N) \approx 1/8$
$P(N|R) \approx 1/20$





To sum up we have, for case $1$: $P(R|N) >P(R)$ and $P(N|R)> P(N)$.
For case $2$, we have: $P(R|N)<P(R)$ and $P(N|R) <P(N)$.

„On the other hand, the Bayes' theorem seems to imply that $P(N|R)<P(N)$ always“ It is unclear where this implication comes from.
Possibly you might have interpreted your expression $$P(N |R) =  \frac{P(N)}{P(N) + \frac{P(R|\overline{N} )}{P(R|N)}(1-P(N))}$$ as  the denominator being always larger than one like misreading it as $$P(N |R) =  \frac{P(N)}{1+ \frac{P(R|\overline{N} )}{P(R|N)}(1-P(N))}$$

Bayes theorem is
$$
P(R|N)P(N)=P(N|R)P(R),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{P(R|N)}{P(R)}=\frac{P(N|R)}{P(N)}.
$$
If the left-hand-side is greater than one, so is the right-hand-side, that is: if $P(R|N)>P(R)$ then also $P(N|R)>P(N)$.
